# How to find the bottleneck at runtime?

Tags: c++, opengl, dynamic, gpu, cpu

I want my cross-platform game to adapt to machines with different processing power autonomously. The goal is to preserve 60 frames per second all the time.

But I cannot make this just depend on the framerate. For example, reducing the AI ticks per second doesn't help, if the application currently is GPU bound. Decreasing the number of samples used for anti aliasing would be better in this situation.

So how can I find out whether the application is bound by CPU or GPU at runtime?

Comment: Maybe you could measure time around each piece of code you think could be a bottleneck and take actions based on this data. Don't know if the overhead of measuring time and analyzing it will give you trouble though.

Comment: I would highly suggest you use OpenGL timer queries if you have access to a somewhat recent implementation of OpenGL. A typical profiler is going to show you the time spent in an API call, and that information is often not useful at all because of the way commands may block when the command queue is full and VSYNC is preventing changes to the back-buffer(s). Timer queries, on the other hand, will give you the time the pipeline actually spent doing work. You can use 1 massive timer query for your entire frame, or break it down into sub-tasks that need performance timing.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman That's a good starting point, thanks for that.

Comment: You could query performance counters (at least on the CPU side), and figure out at any given time whether your program is bounded by CPU (with sub categories of cache/execution/fetch&decode), or memory.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Could you write an answer about that, please?